# Splitting a column with multiple values in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis, data-science

I am trying to split a column in a dataframe in python. 
It looks like this

**col_name**
UO1
UO1,UO2,UO3
UO1,UO2,UO3,UO4,UO5
UO1,SO1,SO3
SO3,UO1

I am not sure how to split them as row values. I am new to python programming

Comment: How to the final dataframe should look like?

Comment: this column is a list of different symptoms a patient has. Since it is possible for a patient to multiple symptoms. I was thinking if its possible to have multiple values from the column to be show for the respective patients? 

I am not quiet sure but I was thinking something like this -

id symptoms
1 UO1
2 UO1
2 UO2
2 UO3

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
df['id'] = df.index+1
df.set_index('id').col_name.str.split(',', expand = True).stack().reset_index(1, drop = True).reset_index(name = 'symptoms')


    id  symptoms
0   1   UO1
1   2   UO1
2   2   UO2
3   2   UO3
4   3   UO1
5   3   UO2
6   3   UO3
7   3   UO4
8   3   UO5
9   4   UO1
10  4   SO1
11  4   SO3
12  5   SO3
13  5   UO1
```

Comment: Thanks Vaishali, Did try the same with slight modification to the code. I am guessing I am doing something really wrong.

Comment: What modifications did you try?